# Script to attach and detach server from the load balancer in amazon aws

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I am using the below Script to attach and detach the server from load balancer

```
#!/bin/bash
aws elb register-instances-with-load-balancer --load-balancer-name Load-BalancerLoadBalancer --instances i-a3f1446e

aws elb deregister-instances-from-load-balancer --load-balancer-name Load-BalancerLoadBalancer --instances i-a3f1446e
```

When I am running the script I am getting the error as below

```
Service elasticloadbalancing not available in region ap-southeast-1b
Service elasticloadbalancing not available in region ap-southeast-1b
```

Is there any changes I want to make the script working or Is there any alternate script to do the work.

Answer (score 1):

The error says `region ap-southeast-1b`, but ap-southeast-1b is an Availability Zone, not a Region.

The Region should be `ap-southeast-1`.

Run `aws configure` and confirm that your Region is set correctly.

Comment: Thanks this should be the answer

Answer (score 0):

Seems your ELB is set in other regions, add `--region` in your command, for example, if the ELB is created at us-east-1:

```
aws elb register-instances-with-load-balancer --load-balancer-name Load-BalancerLoadBalancer --instances i-a3f1446e --region us-east-1

aws elb deregister-instances-from-load-balancer --load-balancer-name Load-BalancerLoadBalancer --instances i-a3f1446e --region us-east-1
```